# File not found- GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, google-signin, google-analytics-sdk

Getting file not found error for `GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a`.

Below is some Google library related content in my Podfile

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.14.0'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging', '~> 1.1.0'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK'
```

Comment: did you make pod install?

Comment: Yes of course I did. It was working fine before I checked out an older branch and did `pod update` after switching back.

Comment: I'm having this issue too - for the same file. Did you have any luck?

Comment: No, I did some modification in `pod update` to avoid updating Google libraries. Seems one of them is causing this issue.

Comment: Any luck fixing it ?

Comment: @imagngames No I decided not to do `pod update` for now due to a critical release. You can try Killian's solution below. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: by the way `Google` cocoapod is up to version 2.0.3 right now; you are limiting it from updating to the latest version. could that be the problem?

Answer (score 9):

If you go to your target's Pod `xcconfig`, i.e `Pods-Development.debug.xcconfig`, near the end of the file there is the entry `-force_load $(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a`.

Getting rid of that fixes the build error. I've not come across any other issues with this as a fix yet. Not sure why this is being added in.

Comment: That did not work for me unfortunately. Can OP tell/validate the answer or if he found another way to solve his problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to update everyone on this, I followed these steps to fix this issue:

1. Deintegrate cocoapod
2. Clear all cache
3. Reinstall cocoapod

Below are some of the commands that will do the trick:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried a lot of different solutions. This one was the only that worked (Working in React Native v: .60+) Thank you